# How to set format datetime in new datacolumn

Tags: c#, datatable

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BeginDate", typeof(DateTime)));

dr["BeginDate"] = Ds.Tables["tDocument"].Rows[i]["vc01"].ToString();
```

How do I set the `datetime` format to `"dd/MM/yyyy"`? Right now, it looks like this:

```
14/09/2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: didn't you try to do with string column?

Comment: How are you showing the data to the user? Is this bound to a grid somewhere?

Comment: It does not make sense to format datasource. It's the matter of the view to format data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a demo:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("BeginDate", typeof(string));

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["BeginDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["BeginDate"]);
}
```

For your case,please try following code:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BeginDate", typeof(string)));

dr["BeginDate"] = Ds.Tables["tDocument"].Rows[i]["vc01"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If you want to sort the datetime column in a datagridview, you just need to change the column format like bellow:

```
dataGrid.Columns["colName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Comment: and if type is string when i'm sort gridview column begindate it's wrong sort because it's see string not date

Comment: @TanNithirot If you use gridview see my answer how to do it correctly.

Comment: when i'm sort buy string
06/11/2018
09/10/2018
13/09/2018
15/09/2018
17/09/2018
27/08/2018
29/08/2018

when i'm sortbuy datetime
06/11/2018
00:00:00
09/10/2018
00:00:00
17/10/2018
00:00:00
15/09/2018
00:00:00
13/09/2018
00:00:00
29/08/2018
00:00:00
27/08/2018

Comment: @TanNithirot Are you suprised?

Comment: @TanNithirot if you bind the datasource to gridview and you want to sort the datetime column, you need to set the column's format.

Comment: @TanNithirot hope you'll see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52324952/1099716

Answer (score 1):

If you use datagridview, then you need to format its column, not the datasource. Otherwise you won't be able to sort column by date. Datagridview will allow you to put anything if you allow it to edit data.

```
var row = dataTable1.NewRow();
row["BeginDate"] = DateTime.Now;
dataTable1.Rows.Add(row);
dataGridView1.Columns["beginDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

beginDateDataGridViewTextBoxColumn  is the name of the dataGridView column which was generated for "BeginDate" column.

if you use combobox, then format it using FormatString:

```
comboBox1.FormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

Answer (score 0):

The / character in date/time format strings stands for "whatever the date separator of the format provider is". Since you do not supply a format provider Thread.CurrentCulture is used, and in your case the current culture uses . as the date separator.
If you want to use a literal slash, place it inside single quotes:

```
Ds.Tables["tDocument"].Rows[i]["vc01"].ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Alternatively, you could specify a format provider where the date separator is /:

```
Ds.Tables["tDocument"].Rows[i]["vc01"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do Like this

```
 dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BeginDate", typeof(String)));
 dr["BeginDate"] = Ds.Tables["tDocument"].Rows[i]["vc01"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```